# How do I use `set cursorline` but keep background color highlights e.g. in quickfix window

Tags: cursorline

If I use `set cursorline`, then lines that have some background color set (like in quickfix windows in vimtex) lose that color.

How can I prevent that?

For example: In the first picture, the cursor is on the second line of the quickfix window. Then I press `k` to go to the first line and the yellow highlighting disappears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Done

Comment: what is the output of `:hi Cursorline`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt `CursorLine     xxx term=underline cterm=underline guibg=Grey40`

Answer (score 1):

The CursorLine highlighting group defines how the current line will be highlighted, once `:set cursorline` is enabled. As you have noticed, it contains an option for setting the background color.

If you do not want that and basically just want the underlining to take place, I would suggest to change the highlighting group to:

```
:hi CursorLine cterm=underline term=underline ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

This will set the background color for the gui and the terminal to be transparent (e.g. use the color that is defined by the corresponding syntax highlighting group).

The CursorLine highlighting group is usually set whenever you source a color scheme. To overwrite your custom CursorLine setting, you can use the `ColorScheme` autocommand like this:

```
:au Colorscheme * :hi CursorLine cterm=underline term=underline ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

This will make sure, the CursorLine highlighting will always be redefined even if a color scheme has set it differently.

Comment: I executed both commands from your answer in my example and it didn't help. `hi: CursorLine` gives `CursorLine     xxx term=underline cterm=underline` while I still see the second picture from my question

Comment: then I don't understand what is wrong with your second picture.

Comment: you mean what I don't like about it or why it is like it is?

Comment: I mean what your problem is

Comment: I'd like the first line in my second picture to have yellow background and still be underlined

Comment: the yellow is a property of that particular line. the underline is a property of the cursorline. i don't see why one (underline of cursorline) should negate the other (yellow background of that particular line)

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like it is impossible, as one does not know the current quickfix item and it doesn't come from the syntax rules. So the CursorLine highlihgting overwrites it